# How to extract values from specific keys from list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list

If I have the following type of data - a list of dictionaries, how can I extract some key values from it?

```
comps = [
{
    "name":'Test1',
    "p_value":0.02,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
},{
    "name":'Test2',
    "p_value":0.05,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
},{
    "name":'Test3',
    "p_value":0.03,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
},{
    "name":'Test4',
    "p_value":0.07,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
},{
    "name":'Test5',
    "p_value":0.03,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
},{
    "name":'Test6',
    "p_value":0.02,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
},{
    "name":'Test7',
    "p_value":0.01,
    "group0_null": 0.0,
    "group1_null": 0.0,
}]
```

**Result**

From the data above, let's say I only want `name` and `p_value`. How can I get this result.

```
[{
    "name":'Test1',
    "p_value":0.02,
},{
    "name":'Test2',
    "p_value":0.05,
},{
    "name":'Test3',
    "p_value":0.03,
},{
    "name":'Test4',
    "p_value":0.07,
},{
    "name":'Test5',
    "p_value":0.03,
},{
    "name":'Test6',
    "p_value":0.02,
},{
    "name":'Test7',
    "p_value":0.01,
}]
```

this shows everything

```
[c for c in comps]
```

This shows only the names
[c['name'] for c in comps]

But if I do this:

```
[c['name','p_value'] for c in comps ]
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-b29459f7b089> in <module>
----> 1 [c['name','p_value'] for c in comps['continuous_explainers'] ]
      2 
      3 # cont_comps = []
      4 
      5 # for c in comps['continuous_explainers']:

<ipython-input-94-b29459f7b089> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [c['name','p_value'] for c in comps['continuous_explainers'] ]
      2 
      3 # cont_comps = []
      4 
      5 # for c in comps['continuous_explainers']:

KeyError: ('name', 'p_value')
```

The real data dictionary is much larger than this. I want to do this so that I can have a list of things that are need.

**UPDATE**

Since some pointed out that the structure of the data that I showed is different from what I receive from the server, here's the code that I used to pull the data.

```
# get all comparisons
comps = source.get_comparison(name='Pr1 vs. Rest')

# only take the continuous explainers 
comps['continuous_explainers'][1:5]
```

**DATA**

```
[{'name': 'Gender',
  'column_index': 2,
  'ks_score': 0.0022329709328575142,
  'p_value': 1.0,
  'quartiles': [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]],
  't_test_p_value': 0.8341377317414621,
  'diff_means': 0.0014959875249118681,
  'primary_group_mean': 0.6312769010043023,
  'secondary_group_mean': 0.6297809134793905,
  'ks_sign': '+',
  'group0_percent_null': 0.0,
  'group1_percent_null': 0.0},
 {'name': 'Gender_Missing_color',
  'column_index': 3,
  'ks_score': 2.220446049250313e-16,
  'p_value': 1.0,
  'quartiles': [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
  't_test_p_value': 1.0,
  'diff_means': 0.0,
  'primary_group_mean': 1.0,
  'secondary_group_mean': 1.0,
  'ks_sign': '0',
  'group0_percent_null': 0.9966523194643712,
  'group1_percent_null': 0.9959153360564427},
 {'name': 'Gender_Missing',
  'column_index': 4,
  'ks_score': 0.0007369834078797544,
  'p_value': 1.0,
  'quartiles': [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]],
  't_test_p_value': 0.40301091478187256,
  'diff_means': -0.0007369834079284866,
  'primary_group_mean': 0.0033476805356288893,
  'secondary_group_mean': 0.004084663943557376,
  'ks_sign': '-',
  'group0_percent_null': 0.0,
  'group1_percent_null': 0.0},
 {'name': 'Male',
  'column_index': 5,
  'ks_score': 0.0029699543407862294,
  'p_value': 0.9999999999915384,
  'quartiles': [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
  't_test_p_value': 0.6740956861786738,
  'diff_means': 0.0029699543407684104,
  'primary_group_mean': 0.6245815399330444,
  'secondary_group_mean': 0.621611585592276,
  'ks_sign': '+',
  'group0_percent_null': 0.0,
  'group1_percent_null': 0.0}]
```

This is the output I get. As mentioned above, I only need some data from this list of dictionaries.

Comment: `[(c['name'], c['p_value']) for c in comps ]`? What is the result you *expect*?

Comment: `[{'name': item['name'], 'p_value': item['p_value']} for item in comps]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga they gave the expected result? Just a list of trimmed-down dicts?

Comment: @roganjosh, I'm getting this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Ha, brilliant. So you don't have that structure at all, it's probably serialized as JSON and so one giant string

Comment: @roganjosh, I don't understand. That's exactly the structure I have. I copied and only removed some data to keep it short and simple for SO

Comment: You can't have, because you've got the same solution from 5 people in comments/answers and you're saying it's complaining about string indices. You haven't given a [mcve]

Comment: @roganjosh, I've updated the question to show the actual data that I receive from the server. But the question remains, even if you think the structure is not the same, and since I'm not as experienced in python, let's say it's not. How do I still solve this problem that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure how to make the answers above work for me. However, I figured another way to do this:

```
test = [(c['name'],c['p_value'], c['group0_percent_null']) for c in comps]
pd.DataFrame(test)

    0   1   2
0   ID  5.374590e-13    0.000000
1   Gender  1.000000e+00    0.000000
2   Gender_Missing_color    1.000000e+00    0.996652
3   Gender_Missing  1.000000e+00    0.000000
4   Male    1.000000e+00    0.000000
... ... ... ...
```

It gave me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new dict for each object in `comparisons`, and initialize it only with `name` and `p_value` keys.

`ex = [{'name': d['name'], 'p_value': d['p_value']} for d in comparisons]`

Answer (score -1):

try

```py
[{'name':c['name'], 'p_value':c['p_value']} for c in comps]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.